# Deleting shadow copies on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, volume-shadow-copy

I have a command-and-control PC that runs a specific Legacy Software. The software is black-box and cannot be modified or changed in behavior. To have "live" insight, I've scheduled a job such that [ShadowSpawn](https://github.com/candera/shadowspawn) makes a shadow copy of software's .\log directory, which gets copied with Robocopy over network to another PC where it then gets parsed by python script and updates "live" on web. Time resolution is a copy every 15min. This is set so because the software does not allow read-only access to logs while running. So this has worked for few months and now ShadowSpawn fails with error code 0x80042317 which translates to "VSS_E_MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_SNAPSHOTS_REACHED". Typical resolution of this problem is usage of Microsoft's VSSADMIN with DELETE command.

The problem is that the PC has VSSADMIN version 1.0 that can only list shadow copies but not delete them. It seems that DELETE command was added with version 1.1 with service pack but my boss will not allow update of OS.

My question is how to delete ALL shadow copies with, let say, every reboot on a bare bones Windows XP? Something like [diskshadow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskshadow) or vssadmin 1.1 would be perfect, but like I said - any update of OS is out of question.

Its important to have in mind that neither OS nor the Software depend on shadow copies for backup or functioning so any-and-all snapshots can be deleted freely at reboot, ideally with scheduled job, invisible to the PC operator.

Any ideas?

Comment: ShadowSpawn is supposed to clean up after itself when the command is finished. I have looked at the code, and indeed it does that. Check if you don't have multiple copies of ShadowSpawn executing a command that never terminates.

Comment: Now, that's interesting! Still, I need to clear existing orphaned snapshots, but this reveals a way forward - make sure that shadowspawn is run in single instance.

Comment: If this wasn't already the case, then I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShadowSpawn is supposed to clean up after itself when the command is finished. I have looked at the code, and indeed it does that. Check if you don't have multiple copies of ShadowSpawn executing a command that never terminates.

Making sure that shadowspawn is run in a single instance is a solution,
but better ensure that `robocopy` does terminate.